# How to open a div in 5 seconds when another div is set to display block

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, settimeout

does anyone know how it would be possible to open the div with the id="myModal3" in 5 seconds only when the div with the id="myModal2" has the inline style to display = "block";

I am just learning javascript and have been spending way too much time on this. The code is here, please help thank you so much in advance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
    <button id="myBtn2">Open Next Modal</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Another Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>This is the other Modal and I want to open the next modal automatically in 5 seconds.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Last Modal -->
<div id="myModal3" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Hello there, this is the last modal.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var modal2 = document.getElementById("myModal2");
var modal3 = document.getElementById("myModal3");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

btn2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  modal2.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a timeout when setting `display` for modal2.

```js
btn2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(() => {
    modal3.style.display = "block";
    /*or however you want to display modal3*/
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: thank you so so much :D i used setTimeout instead of setTimeOut and it worked

Comment: Great! I fixed the typo in my answer.